# Group with editable Objects?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Is there a way to have editable objects in a `fabric.Group`, so that it is possible to move one of the objects?

Comment: You should be able to ungroup an object from the group. You'll then be able to modify it independently.

Comment: @kangax Well, thats works. Maybe let me describe my target: A "editable polygon object" … so you can modify the single points of the group (polygon) but if you click in the center of it, you can modify the hole group. At the moment, i built a new Object based on the fabric.Group, but i dont find a way to get a "click"-event from the child-objects …

Comment: I see... Unfortunately, no way to get click on child objects yet.

Comment: Ok, thanks you very much! By the way: fabrics.js is realy awesome. Great code! Maybe it could become near to perfect with object-events and child-objects. A little bit of sprites and movieClips from the actionscript 3 world, you know? :-) Stay awesome!

Comment: @kangax is this functionality implemented in the last version of fabric (currently 1.2.10) - i.e. is it now possible to click on child objects within groups and  edit them independently without ungrouping?

Comment: @LorenzoPolidori No, nothing like this yet. But we'll likely soon have an option for group children to receive their own events.

Comment: @kangax is this implemented in the current version? I'm want to be able to group a text and an circle and the edit the text preserving the group so moving the circle and the text together

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I have not testing this code independently.

Something like this might be a work around, at least we can slightly detect the child objects.

```
var $canvas = {};
$canvas.activePaths = [];

function onMouseDown = function (options) {

    var mousePos = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
    mousePos.x = parseInt(mousePos.x);
    mousePos.y = parseInt(mousePos.y);

    var width =  canvas.getWidth();
    var height = canvas.getHeight();

    var pixels = canvas.getContext().getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    var pixel = (mousePos.x + mousePos.y * pixels.width) * 4;

    var activePathsColor = new fabric['Color']('rgb(' + pixels.data[pixel] + ',' + pixels.data[pixel + 1] + ',' + pixels.data[pixel + 2] + ')');
    var colorHex = '#' + activePathsColor.toHex().toLowerCase();

    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    var activePath = [];

    if(activeObject.type == 'group') {

          for (var i = 0; i < activeObject.getObjects().length; i++) {
            var path = activeObject.getObjects()[i];
            if (path.getFill().toLowerCase() == colorHex) {
                $canvas.activePaths.push(path);
            }
        }

    }

}

function warpActiveObject() {
    for(var i = 0; i < $canvas.activePaths.length; i++) {
        canvas.add(
            new fabric.Rect({
                left: $canvas.getActiveObj().left + ($canvas.activePaths[i].left),
                top: $canvas.getActiveObj().top + ($canvas.activePaths[i].top),
                fill: '',
                width: $canvas.activePaths[0].width,
                height: $canvas.activePaths[0].height,
                stroke: 'white', 
                opacity: 0.5 
            })
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a fiddle for the same example?